# Visual Studio fails to display some watched expressions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, expression

In Visual Studio, most of my objects and variables cannot be resolved during a debugging session for various reasons.  This means I cannot inspect or watch objects or their invoke their functions making it extremely difficult to debug my code because most of my expressions simply won't work.  Some typical errors I get when adding an expression to the watch window include:

- CXX0019: Error: bad type cast
- CXX0059: Error: left operand is class not a function name
- CXX0058: Error: overloaded operator not found

Most often these expressions involve overloaded operators and/or template class objects.

Why is this happening? how do you fix it?

Comment: can you post some expressions? using the watch windows with complex algeritms(operators) is asking for troubles imho

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The errors you have are due to limitations in the debugger, there are not bugs as Daniel implies.

The watch window cannot call overloaded operators.
If you have e.g. a `std::vector<int> vecSomething` you cannot put `vecSomething[0]` into the watch window, because `std::vector<int>::operator[]` is an overloaded operator. Consequently, for a vector of objects, you cannot do `vecObject[0].SomeMemberVariableOfObject` in the watch window. You could write `vecObject._Myfirst[0].SomeMemberVariableOfObject`. In Visual Studio's STL implementation, `_Myfirst` is a member of vector pointing at the first element.

If you add your own variables and types to the watch window, add watches to the data members directly. It is no problem to follow chains of pointers like `member.memberStruct.ptrToObj->memberOfObj`.

Edit:

Actually Visual Studio can call code in the Watch window:
[http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/02/14/visual-studio-2008-debugging-ndash-the-watch-window.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160709084800/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/02/14/visual-studio-2008-debugging-ndash-the-watch-window.aspx)

Thus, it is slightly mysterious why overloaded operators cannot be used.

Comment: @stijn: Can you elaborate? It does evaluate expressions, i.e., you can watch "(a+b)/2", it does evaluate code to format expressions following rules given in autoexp.dat, but when does it execute my code?

Comment: @stijn: Updated my post. I found out that you are right, calling functions is allowed in the watch window. I didn't know that.

Comment: I think I recall seeing overloaded operator functions being evaluated in the watch window "once in a blue moon" but most often they definitely do not evaluate.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this happening?

The tool has its limitations. For example, many times I "go to definition" and the definition is not found. I have to "find in files". It is no surprise that some expressions are not evaluated during debugging sessions, either.

> How do you fix it?

- Keep expressions simple. Do not
  concatenate them directly, use
  variables with explanatory names for
  intermediate results.
- Support your code with explicit assertions. If it's "wrong", an assertion should fail.

Comment: I cannot remember, is there a native assert operator in C++?  Or must one devise their own?

Moreover, do you think it would work to write wrapper functions as interfaces to commonly inspected expressions to work-around this debugger limitation?  That incurs a little more programming overhead, but I cannot think of a better approach just yet.

Comment: @Jonny assert is a macro. It is typically defined by the compiler vendor. And yes, writing extra functions would help clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

The problem and possible workarounds are precisely described in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/e0ysa1hs(v%3dvs.100))

> The debugger accepts most Microsoft and ANSI C/C++ expressions; however, you do need to be aware of the following:
>
> Unsupported Operators and Additional Operators
>
> Restrictions on Native C++ Expressions

Comment: Thanks, however I note that the documentation appears to be wrong for VS2008: it says that overloaded `operator[]()` will work, but adding a watch `v[42]` for a variable `vector<int> v` gives the CXX0058 error -- even if `42` is changed to `42U` or `42L` or `42LU` to satisfy the requirement of exact type matching of arguments.  Maybe it doesn't work w.r.t. templates?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Maybe it is because of the template, I don't know since I never used VS2008. When the `[]` operator doesn't work in the watch window you can display the internal members of the vector Class and add an offset to watch the data you want to see, but this is quite slower than typing `v[42]`.

Comment: The linked documentation is for *managed* C++. i.e. C++/CLI. Different evaluator, different supported functionality. It's not relevant to the original question. Boxing and properties don't even exist in C++ as first class concepts. From the linked page you can get to correct docs for native code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/99dwf401%28v%3dvs.100%29

Comment: @Adam I changed the link.

Answer (score 3):

I found one solution which solves (to some extent) the issue of overloaded operators. It seems to not depend on the internals of the class. You have to use the expanded form of the operator call. Here's an example for `vector<int> v`:

```
v.operator[](0)
```

I tested it in Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: With the operator call for a map in VS2010 says: 'CX0039: Error: symbol is ambiguous'

Answer (score 2):

PDB file management is far from perfect, certainly in larger projects. In particular, VS has the rather stupid behavior of merging all symbols in VSxx.PDB, even across different projects. The /Fd switch can easily fix this; pass `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to nested classes
Example :

```
    class A
    {
        class B
        {
            int i;
        };
    };
```

cast like (B*)(0x12345678) will fail, but (A::B*)(0x12345678) will succeeded